# Swing JList and Array

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to add some elements from array. I am lost with java API. It must be in this format so I can make things in order.

```
    listOfItem = new JList();

    for (int i = 0; i < car.length; ++i) {
        listOfItem.add(car[i].getId() + ": ", car[i].getDescription(),
            (car[i].getPrice()), car[i].getQuantity());
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using a JList to display multiple columns of data. Instead use a JTable. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information and working examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add elements to the JList directly. Use a `ListModel` to provide data for your `JList`:

```
listOfItem = new JList();

// create list model 
DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < car.length; ++i) {
  listModel.addElement(car[i].getId() + ": " + car[i].getDescription() + ", " +
          car[i].getPrice() + ", " + car[i].getQuantity();
}
// register model so that the list shows the data of the model
listOfItem.setModel(listModel);
```